# Google Colaboratoryを使ったkerasでmodel.saveができない

Tags: python, 機械学習, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

画像認識プログラミングレシピという本で画像認識を学習中です。
kerasでモデルを保存しようとするとエラーが出て保存できません。
以下のサイトが参考になるかなと思ったのですが、読んでもよく理解できませんでした。

[Kerasでmodel.saveしようとしてmust override `get_config`エラーが出たときの対処](https://qiita.com/taiga518/items/b2154b661e7baf56031e)

文字数の関係上モデルの一部を抜粋させていただきました。
必要な情報があればコメントお願いします。

モデル

```
model = Sequential()

#学習方法を決める

#(学習スタイル, 損失関数, 正解かどうかの評価方法)
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
            loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
            metrics=["accuracy"])

print("反復学習回数:", EPOCHS)
fit_record = model.fit(train_data, train_teacher_labels, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, validation_data=(test_data, test_teacher_labels))

#ニューラルネットワークの構築

#畳み込み層(入力のニューロン数, 畳み込みエリアの幅と高さ, 活性化関数, 入力データの形式)
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"))
#プーリング層
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
#ドロップアウト層(過学習を防ぐ)
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
#入力を平滑化する
model.add(Flatten())
#全結合層(ノード数が128個, 活性化関数)
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#出力層(ノーど数がnum_classes個になる)
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))
```

エラーが出たところ

```
model.save("keras-mnist-model.h5")
```

エラー内容

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-a2ac93d46f7c> in <module>()
----> 1 model.save("keras-mnist-model.h5")

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in get_config(self)
    719       raise NotImplementedError('Layer %s has arguments in `__init__` and '
    720                                 'therefore must override `get_config`.' %
--> 721                                 self.__class__.__name__)
    722     return config
    723 

NotImplementedError: Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config`.
```

keras 2.5.0
tensorflow 2.5.0
numpy 1.19.5
macOSX
google colab

Comment: それで、解決したんでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

MNISTを例にすると以下のようなコードになります。

- モデルのcompileはアーキテクチャを作った後に行ってください。
- モデルの訓練(fitメソッドを呼ぶこと)はアーキテクチャを作ってcompileをしたあとで行ってください。
- データのshapeが正常であるかを確認してください。

```py
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 1000
NUM_CLASSES = 10

x_train = x_train.astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.astype("float32") / 255
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1)
x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, -1)
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, NUM_CLASSES)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, NUM_CLASSES)

model = Sequential()

model.add(keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
            loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
            metrics=["accuracy"])

fit_record = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

model.save("keras-mnist-model.h5")
```